# Evaluating a mathematical expression given as text

Tags: c#, string, int

I'm trying to make a calculator-like program where one would enter a calculation in a textbox and it would convert that calculation to an `int` with the result, here's what I have but it doesn't work much

```
string calcStr = textBox1.Text;
int result = calcStr;
```

Any suggestions that aren't too complicated?

Comment: I hear regular expressions would make this super easy...

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich, What you hear is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) for this kind of job... it is free, comes with source and does all the heavy lifting (parse the mathematical expression etc.) and gives you the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correct you want to be able to parse an expression like 1 + 3 + 4 from a textbox and execute a calculation based on the input. That is actually a harder task than one might think.

One common solution is to use the Shunting-yard algorithm to parse the expression. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm for more details.

Comment: The question doesn't state the format of the string, that he seeks to parse. This is a good answer for the common infix notation. However, I would mention that if the input could be obtained in polish notation, the actual calculation algorithm is a lot easier to implement. (+1).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to simply parse out the number from a string, use a function like

```
Int32.Parse(string)
```

If you need to take out an EQUATION, like
"3+4/2"
then you'll need to extract each character one at a time and determine what it is.

Like if the string was
"32+4/12"
You'd have to loop through every character in the string, and try to parse the current character into a number.
Theres a function to test if it's a number or not. or just check it's ascii value.

if it succeeds, take the current number plus the next one and try again until you hit a non-number character.
Now you can extract your numbers.
Characters that are not numbers are checked against the mathmatical operators you're allowing. Anything else throws an error.

Once you can extract all the whole equation, you'll probably have to do something like Stack operations to evaluate it. I believe in my Assembly class you'd push a buncha numbers and operators to the stack, and then pop it one at a top from the top, evaluating the previous number with the next number by the operator in between.

I hope this is what you were talking about. Best of luck!